# VB.net difficulty in using RedirectStandardInput for my program

Tags: vb.net, cmd, netcat

I am trying to make a simple chat program in vb using netcat. Here is my code

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim p As New Process
    Dim pstrt As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Go()
    End Sub
    Sub Go()
        pstrt.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        pstrt.Arguments = "/c nc -l -p1234"
        pstrt.UseShellExecute = False
        pstrt.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        pstrt.RedirectStandardInput = True
        AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf yo
        p.StartInfo = pstrt
        p.Start()
        p.BeginOutputReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub yo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        UpdateTextBox(e.Data)
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxDelegate(ByVal Text As String)
    Private Sub UpdateTextBox(ByVal tot As String)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim delgt As New UpdateTextBoxDelegate(AddressOf UpdateTextBox)
            Dim args As Object() = {tot}
            Me.Invoke(delgt, args)
        Else
            RichTextBox1.Text &= tot & Environment.NewLine
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'Shell(TextBox1.Text)
        'Console.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)

    End Sub
End Class
```

The form has a `richtextbox`, a `textbox` and `two buttons`.
The problem is that:

1. when using redirectstandardinput, the received text is not displayed in richtextbox but the sent text can be viewed by the receiver.
2. when I don't redirectstandardinput then the received text is displayed in the richtextbox but the sent text cannot be viewed by the receiver.
3. I have also tried to use the commented code (for button2 click code) to use to send text when not using redirectstandardinput.

Comment: Hello, is anyone there !

Answer (score 0):

For me, your code is working correctly without changes, with

```vb
pstrt.RedirectStandardOutput = True
pstrt.RedirectStandardInput = True
```

See the screenshot:

[image]

I guess your problem can be with netcat.

- Try with simple commands first like seen on the sample.
- Try on another machine. I tested on Windows 8.0, .NET 4.0.